# Internet speed is not reflected in the performance of the pages

Tags: networking, router, performance, internet

I have a weird problem with the internet speed: recently the ISP replaced the equipment that is receiving the fiber signal and transforming it into ethernet signal that is connected to my personal router.

After this change, the speed tests still indicate high speeds, but unfortunatelly the actual performance of the internet is definitely worse...

I tried to bypass the personal router to debug the problem and the same issue appears when the laptop has a Broadband connection directly through ethernet cable and to their device.

```
IPS               Street      Home
[IPS Server] ---- Fiber ----> [IPS Bridge] --- ETH --> [Laptop]
```

Specifically, the speed indicated by speedtest.net is around **200Mbps / 160Mbps** (ping 1ms). However, sometimes websites like Google, Facebook etc. simply hang around 10 seconds and then *slowly* they load, or in the worst case they just time out.

I tried connecting my laptop to my mobile hotspot device with an SIM chip, and the internet *feels* way faster at speeds around **30-40Mbps**.

I am wondering: why is that?

Could it be that the ISP is tricking somehow the speed testers to show higher values?

I am guessing the problem has to do with the new device they replaced, but they do not observe any disconnections.

Before they changed the device, the internet *felt* way faster.

Comment: What does Wireshark show during those 10 seconds? It seems you're talking about two different things here; the part that _hangs around_ or _feels faster_ is mainly the connection establishment, not the actual data transfer. Whether the browser can _reliably_ make DNS queries and connect to the servers has really nothing to do with how fast it can receive data after that's done.

Comment: Ask the ISP whether there is an issue with their physical gateway or DNS servers.

Comment: Try an alternative DNS server (Google, Cloudflare, …). Also check your latency (“ping”), most speed tests display it, too. You should also check for packet loss.

Comment: @DanielB I tried an alternative DNS server, but that did not make any change at all. The ping looks good (1ms) when speedtest.net is set to automatic server. When I change it to a custom server from San Francisco or London, the latency may increase up to 150ms... I checked the packet loss, but it tends to be 0.

Comment: @user1686 After testing the ETH connection  directly to the bridge device, I noticed that usually that those delays of 10 seconds preceed the disconnection of the broadband connection. Then I have to click Connect again and it works for another 30-40 minutes...

Comment: Quick update: the ISP replaced their equipment with a new one and this one works just fine. The question still remains: how come, for a speed measured at 200Mbps and low latency, the connexion would feel very slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of weeks/months, coming with an update on this.

While I do not have an explanation why the Speed tests were indicating very high speeds, while the webpages and the internet in general was terribly slow, the problem got solved by the ISP by changing the router device.

I installed a software on Windows to test the internet speed in realtime for longer periods of time, inserted the Ethernet cable directly into my laptop (not through the router). What I observed was that, while the internet was very fast, after around 1-5 minutes it would disconnect from the ISP server.

---

After they changed the router device the internet is fast, and yes, it is fast.